# make Owin object from list of coordinates

Tags: r, polygon, spatial, r-sp, spatstat

I'm trying to build species distribution polygons for use in the R program [rase](https://rdrr.io/cran/rase/man/rase-package.html). The program requires an owin object but sample data also includes a SpatialPolygonDataFrame. You can get the data yourself with: `data(rase_data, package = 'rase')`

I'm starting with a list of coordinates (lat/long per species). Thanks to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58622586/how-to-construct-plot-convex-hulls-of-polygons-from-points-by-factor-using-sf), I've been able to make a polygon per element of the list (each species). I need to get to an owin object. Here's the dput of some test data and then code I've used to get where I'm at.

```
#dput(specieslist)
specieslist <- structure(list(Species = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "M", "A", "M", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "M", "M", "A", "M", "A", "A", "A", "M", "M", "M", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "M", "A", "A", "M", "M", "A", "M", "M", "A"), lat = c(37.407002, 35.65242, 33.33891, 37.65105, 38.90657, 39.06893, 34.53998, 38.18311, 37.40006, 35.65242, 34.53998, 33.33891, 37.65105, 38.90657, 38.18311, 39.06893, 36.252183, 40.32555, 39.575983, 39.73548, 39.73548, 37.82096, 39.71557, 38.7222, 35.58556, 36.3075, 36.208, 33.967875, 35.375, 39.73589, 38.75774, 36.61058, 37.63605, 36.586111, 40.63344, 39.80565, 39.72601, 39.70529, 40.50957, 37.81238), long = c(-122.232016, -120.77931, -116.91402, -119.88513, -121.05138, -120.86546, -119.85962, -120.37691, -122.23219, -120.77931, -119.85962, -116.91402, -119.88513, -121.05138, -120.37691, -120.86546, -121.775867, -121.91209, -121.554167, -121.70126, -121.70126, -120.14661, -121.61181, -120.98745, -120.9122, -121.4806, -121.816, -120.097752, -120.6456, -121.70175, -120.8443, -119.05645, -119.8728, -121.914722, -121.87499, -121.71465, -121.76862, -121.53125, -122.10229, -120.42828)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -40L))
```

Make the polygon per species/points by creating hull around points:

```
#create simple feature
library(sf)
df.sf <- specieslist %>%
  st_as_sf( coords = c("long", "lat" ), crs = 4326 )
# perform fast visual check using mapview-package
#mapview::mapview( df.sf )

#group and summarise by species, and draw hulls
hulls <- df.sf %>%
  group_by( Species ) %>%
  summarise( geometry = st_combine( geometry ) ) %>%
  st_convex_hull()
##result
#mapview::mapview( list(df.sf, hulls ) )
```

Now I think `df.sf` (sf points object) becomes the SpatialPolygonDataFrame and `hulls` (sf polygon object) becomes an owin object:

```
as(df.sf, "Spatial") -> df.sf_SPDF #this formats incorrectly though.

distribution <- st_transform(hulls, crs = 6345)
Dist_owin <- as.owin(as_Spatial(distribution))

#Error: Only projected coordinates may be converted to spatstat class objects
```

#OR

```
as.owin(distribution)
#Error: 'owin' is not an exported object from 'namespace:spatstat'
maptools::as.owin(distribution)
#Error: 'as.owin' is not an exported object from 'namespace:maptools'
```

The problems are: `df.sf_SPDF` seems to be formatted incorrectly and `Dist_owin` errors.
I find all this spatial work in R very confusing. I've been working on this for several days now.

UPDATE: If I try another way-  convert geometry to polygon and then make the owin. This produces an error:

```
hulls_poly <- st_cast(distribution$geometry, "POLYGON") #. 
Dist_owin <- as.owin(as_Spatial(hulls_poly))
#ERROR:  no method or default for coercing “sfc_POLYGON” to “owin”
```

Comment: Do you have coordinates of the polygon defining your study region (observation window - `owin`)? Or do you data only contain the coordinates of presence of a given species? If your data don't have information of your study region, you can use the convex polygon containing the data, but it may introduce bias depending on the analysis you make.

Comment: @EgeRubak Thanks for the reply. No, I don't have the study window/owin and am trying to create that - hence my question on how to do that. I'll eventually be refining the convex hull I create in the code above to better define the species distributions. I want to use coordinates to build the convex hulls to represent the study region. I just can't seem to format the created SpatialPolygon to owin - one window per species. I've updated the code and I think this how it should all work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know `sf` enough to fix this, so I show it via `terra` but the important part is the sequence of operations. You can implement that in `sf` again if you wish. There should be no need to revert to the old `Spatial*` objects

Your data

```
specieslist <- structure(list(Species = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "M", "A", "M", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "M", "M", "A", "M", "A", "A", "A", "M", "M", "M", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "M", "A", "A", "M", "M", "A", "M", "M", "A"), lat = c(37.407002, 35.65242, 33.33891, 37.65105, 38.90657, 39.06893, 34.53998, 38.18311, 37.40006, 35.65242, 34.53998, 33.33891, 37.65105, 38.90657, 38.18311, 39.06893, 36.252183, 40.32555, 39.575983, 39.73548, 39.73548, 37.82096, 39.71557, 38.7222, 35.58556, 36.3075, 36.208, 33.967875, 35.375, 39.73589, 38.75774, 36.61058, 37.63605, 36.586111, 40.63344, 39.80565, 39.72601, 39.70529, 40.50957, 37.81238), long = c(-122.232016, -120.77931, -116.91402, -119.88513, -121.05138, -120.86546, -119.85962, -120.37691, -122.23219, -120.77931, -119.85962, -116.91402, -119.88513, -121.05138, -120.37691, -120.86546, -121.775867, -121.91209, -121.554167, -121.70126, -121.70126, -120.14661, -121.61181, -120.98745, -120.9122, -121.4806, -121.816, -120.097752, -120.6456, -121.70175, -120.8443, -119.05645, -119.8728, -121.914722, -121.87499, -121.71465, -121.76862, -121.53125, -122.10229, -120.42828)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -40L))
```

First I make a spatial object, a `SpatVector` in this case, and I transform it to a planar CRS --- to get that out of the way.

Your choice of `epsg:6345`, that is `+proj=utm +zone=16` is inappropriate for your data. Zone 16 is for the longitude of Alabama. California covers two UTM zones so you cannot use that. Instead use e.g. "Teale Albers" if all your data are confined to the Golden State.

```
 library(terra)
 #terra version 1.2.5
 v <- vect(specieslist, c("long", "lat"), crs="epsg:4326")
 tacrs <- "+proj=aea +lat_1=34 +lat_2=40.5 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-120 +x_0=0 +y_0=-4000000 +datum=NAD83 +units=m"
 v <- project(v, tacrs)
```

To simplify things, I show a workflow for 1 species

```
usp <- unique(v$Species)  
sp <- v[v$Species==usp[1]]
```

Make a convex hull, and I think you would want to add a buffer.

```
ch <- terra::convexhull(sp)
bch <- buffer(ch, 25000)

plot(bch)
points(sp)
```

Now make the owin via `sf`

```
library(sf)
library(spatstat)
sfobj <- st_as_sf(bch)
owin <- as.owin(sfobj)
```

You can extract the points in new CRS like this

```
pxy <- terra::coords(sp)
```

And now create a spatstat `ppp` object.

```
x <- ppp(pxy[,1], pxy[,2], window=owin)
#Warning message:
#data contain duplicated points
```

To avoid the above warning, you could use, at the start of the script, `specieslist <- unique(specieslist)`

```
x
#Planar point pattern: 27 points
#window: polygonal boundary
#enclosing rectangle: [-222286.97, 312378.62] x [-539742.6, 217425] units
```

Comment: Thank you SO much for taking the time. I'm still working through your answer, but I'm confused how to find the best CRS? My data actually covers not only California but several states in western USA. Could you direct me to a resource that applies here?

Comment: You could search for "map projection for the contiguous USA". Eg. Albers like this `+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=37.5 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84`  but you could center it on the western states by moving the `lon_0` parameter to the west. There are many resources, including https://spatialreference.org/

Comment: What version of sf and/or spatstat are you using? I'm still getting an error on the steps to convert to owin: `sfobj <- st_as_sf(bch)` Results in: `no applicable method for 'st_as_sf' applied to an object of class "SpatVector"`. I'm using sf 0.9-4 and spatstat 2.1-0. I see here it should work:https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1567

Comment: You answered your own question: you need to use the current package versions. Your version of `sf` is old.

Comment: In case it is helpful for others: for some reason I had to remove my sf package completely in order to update it properly. @RobertHijmans Thank you so much for all your help. I've been working on this for longer than it should take...